# Register com interop dll in .net

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, com-interop, installshield

I am working on a Installshield Project which have 4 .net com interop dlls.

- I used command `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Regasm.exe /tlb myassembly.dll /codebase` to register the assemblies.
- Now my question is, when VS2010 is installed on the machine,
  Installer works properly. But If VS2010 is not installed on the
  machine, only dot net Framework is installed, Installer doesn't work
  properly and throws an error "Make sure the Object is entered in the
  system registry".
- Can any body please tell me the cause of issue.

Comment: Why not just have installshield extract the COM information at build time?

Comment: I tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

COM Extract at Build is for unmanaged DLL's.  The .NET COM Interop property is for COM Visible.  This will cause InstallShield to perform a regasm /regfile during the build process and harvest the result into the Registry table.  During the installation the registry will be written without needing to call out of process to Regasm.

There is a note in Regasm on MSDN about /regfile not executing / capturing user registration code.  If this process still isn't good enough, use a tool such as InstallWatch to capture / diff the before and after of the registry to observe what was 'missing' and then author that in InstallShield in the registry view.  Rebuild, reset the VM and rinse and repeat until it works.

Answer (score 0):

This "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Regasm.exe /tlb myassembly.dll /codebase" works only if you have .NET 4.0 and higher installed on target machine.
For previous .NET versions run Regasm.exe from 2.0.5077 folder:
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.5077\Regasm.exe /tlb myassembly.dll /codebase"

see registry HKLM\Software\Microsoft.NET Framework\ for more info anbout .NET versions installed